# Frame-by-frame value for pitch and intensity?

Tags: praat

Is there a way I can view the frame-by-frame value for pitch and intensity on Praat? As of now, I can only view the mean pitch and intensity across the whole time window of my recording. I have included the code that I have used so far. When I run the code, I get the following error message: [Picture of error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejd2d.jpg). Thanks in advance for your help!

'''
#creating a table for the values
timeseriesp = Create Table with column names: "timeseriesp", 0,"p_ts"

#reading in the file
sound = Read from file: fileName$

#selecting the sound object and extracting continuous pitch
selectObject: sound
View & Edit
#610 is length of video
Select: 0, 610
p_ts = Pitch listing

#putting data into the table
selectObject: timeseriesp
Append row
row = Get number of rows
Set string value: row, "test", p_ts
'''

Comment: Is what you want just to be able to visually see the pitch and intensity in at each point when looking at a spectrogram? Or do you have a script and want to extract the pitch and intensity every X milliseconds?

Comment: I have a script, and would like to extract the info at every milliseconds

Comment: Great, can you post the script that you currently have? If we see where you are with the code, then we can help you get the results that you want

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can you put the code in your original post by editing it? You can start a code chunk with three ticks ``` and then end it the same way

Comment: @sjp Thanks! I have added the code to the original post + a picture of the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Two points here.
First, the error message you are getting is due to you trying to use an editor command ("Select"). In roder to avoid the error, embed the command in an editor -- endeditor structure:

```
editor sound
   Select: 0, 610
endeditor
```

Second, in general though, you can get pitch and intensity values quicker without reverting to the editor window. This will speed up your script if you are processing a lot of files.
Create Pitch and Intensity objects from your sound file. You can query those objects for pitch/intensity values at specific times/frames and save them in your table.